# bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long

Tags: list, ls, fastq

I need to make a list of a large number of files (40,000 files) like below:

```
ERR001268_1_100.fastq  ERR001268_2_156.fastq  ERR001753_2_78.fastq
ERR001268_1_101.fastq  ERR001268_2_157.fastq  ERR001753_2_79.fastq
ERR001268_1_102.fastq  ERR001268_2_158.fastq  ERR001753_2_7.fastq
ERR001268_1_103.fastq  ERR001268_2_159.fastq  ERR001753_2_80.fastq
```

my command is: `ls ERR*_1_*.fastq |sed 's/\.fastq//g'|sort -n > masterlist`
However error is: `bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long`

However can I solve this problem?
Any other way to make list like this by perl/python?

thx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be able to replace `ls ERR*_1_*.fastq` with `find . -name "ERR*_1_*.fastq"`.
This way, you can avoid having the wildcard expand into a huge argument list.

(The `find` output will include a leading "./", e.g. `./ERR001268_1_100.fastq` . If
that's undesirable, you can get rid of it with another `sed` command later in the
pipeline.)

Answer (score 1):

If the files already all exist within your directory, python's "glob" module might have a higher limit than bash's command line.

From the command line:

```
python -c "import glob; print glob.glob('ERR_*_1_*.fastq')"
```

To do the whole thing in python, the you could try something like this:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob("ERR_*_1_*.fastq")
trimmedfiles = [x.replace(".fastq","") for x in files]
trimmedfiles.sort()
for f in trimmedfiles:
    print f
```

This solution will sort the files alphabetically, and not numerically.  For that you might want to add some key=lambda magic to the sort() method:

```
trimmedfiles.sort(key=lambda f: int(f.split("_")[2]))
```

Comment: You probably want a `'\n'.join(...)` around the glob call. Otherwise, this answer got me out of a similar situation, +1

Answer (score 0):

Find might help you - rather then ls use `find . -name 'yourpatternhere' -print0 | xargs -0 youractionhere`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find`.

Example:

```
find /Users/kunlun/Downloads/fu_neg/ -name "*.png" > 
/Users/kunlun/Downloads/fu_neg.txt
```